# Pass an uploaded file in Flask directly to scikit-image

Tags: python, flask, scikit-image

I upload a file to Flask and can access it with `request.files`. I want to read this file on the fly with scikit-image to do some processing. How can I load the image directly from the uploaded data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uploaded file object can be passed directly to `skimage.io.imread`.

```
import skimage
image_data = request.files['image_data']
image = skimage.io.imread(image_data)
```